# Conditions of validity of Sargent rule?

Tags: particle-physics, weak-interaction

In Perkins (2000, [link](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=e63cNigcmOUC&source=gbs_navlinks_s) to Google Books) the following statement is made about Sargent rule:

> Discovered empirically in nuclear $\beta$-decay, but applicable to any three-body weak decay, ... (pg 405 4th ed)

To me this statement seem dubious; the author himself demonstrates it for $\beta$ decay only in the relativistic limit (pg 200).  My question is therefore:

For a given weak, 3-body,  decay:
\[A\rightarrow B+C+D\]
Under what conditions does Sargent rule hold?

---

For those who don't know - Sargent rule states that the Decay rate is proportional to the 5th power of the disintegration energy ($Q$-value)

Comment: Sargent's rule works best for a one-scale model, i.e. when the available energy quantifying the phase space of available states in Fermi's Golden rule is larger than product masses. For a weak decays, $\Gamma \propto G_F^2$. If the only dominant scale around is Q, dimensional analysis dictates $\Gamma \propto G_F^2 ~ Q^5$.

Comment: PS the 5th power of the density of states in [Fermi's Golden Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%27s_golden_rule)  is discussed [here](http://hep.ucsb.edu/courses/ph125_02/fgr_schw.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

Sargent's rule is derived in  the [four fermi interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%27s_interaction) model of weak decays.

A more general derivation (within the fermi model) than the relativistic approximation   can be seen [here](http://www.hep.phy.cam.ac.uk/~lester/teaching/Lectures_4.ppt), 4th page .

[image: sargent]

The four fermi interaction is the low energy limit of the weak decay described through gauge boson exchanges, with only three track vertices allowed.